# How do I have a Row Group "under" a Column Group in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

I have some data that relates to some production inputs and outputs. 
What I want to do is, for each production run, show what went in and what came out.

I have, at this point, something that looks like this:

```
Run#   Item   Input    Output
1      X          1         
       Y                    1

2      A          2         
       B          3         2
       C                    3
```

Where Input/Output is derived from a 'direction' column group, and there are row groups on Run# and Item.
What I want is something like this:

```
Run#   Item   Input    Item    Output
1         X       1       Y         1

2         A       2       B         2
          B       3       C         3
```

Is this even possible? I feel like it should be, but as you can probably see from the title, I don't even know what to begin searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to add a rank() over the query like so:

```
dense_rank() OVER (Run#, Direction Order By ItemCode) as rank
```

You can then perform a row grouping by the `rank` field (you don't have to display the column), and add `ItemCode` as a column in the column grouping.